# I can't install Ubuntu 22.04 after USB boot

Tags: system-installation

[image]

I downloaded Ubuntu 22.04 mounted on sub by UltraISO. after restarting laptop and choosing USB from boot options I get that "no system disk. booting from hard disk. start booting from USB device.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

please try to use a different software to create the usb drive, like Rufus. Are you installing ubuntu on a new computer or an old one? Because if you are installing on an old computer control on internet how works GPT and MBR, if it is old maybe you need to create the usb bootable with MBR.
Be sure to have disabled the Secure Boot into the BIOS.